# VBA - Format timestamp with colons

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

Is there a way to format the timestamp with colons? So when this notebook is saved the date shows as `d-mm-yyyy` and the time shows as `hh:mm:ss ampm`? When I replace the dashes with semicolons for the time it produces the VBA error 400.

```
& Format(Now, "d-mm-yyyy hh-mm-ss ampm")
```

Comment: do you want colons or semi colons?

Comment: @ScottCraner Colons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the `-` with `:`

```
& Format(Now, "d-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

to use `;`:

```
& Format(Now, "d-mm-yyyy hh\;mm\;ss AM/PM")
```

Comment: I tried that, but when I run the save it produces an error 400

Comment: Then show more of your code because the error is not there. if you put `? Format(Now, "d-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")` it returns the correct answer.

Comment: Okay, I am using windows which is why it wont allow to save with a colon. Would the same work with semi colons?

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to save an actual file with colons in the filename, that is not allowed on Windows. You cannot have colons in Windows filenames. (I am assuming you are using Windows.)

Comment: Yes I am, didn't even realize that. Thank you.